# Advice on where to install Redis

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, haproxy, redis

I have just introduced Redis into our application and I am not sure where best to install in production. I read that the Windows option is not production quality so i need to install on Linux.

I currently have 5 redhat boxes and cannot get any more provisioned at this current time. These consist of Active/Passive HaProxy load balancer and a cluster of three RabbitMQ boxes.

Where would you install the Active/Passive redis instances?

Update - My knowledge of linux is limited. i do not know if it is normal to install apps alongside HaProxy or should a HaProxy instance be left as a SRP box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you asking for?

Redis is not officially supported on Windows, so there should be no question about installing it on the RHEL boxes.

Redis RPMs are available at http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=redis

Redis is a memory hungry process, so you will want to install it on the instances that have the most spare RAM.

Comment: I was asking given the choice between the haproxy cluster or rabbitmq cluster where would you install redis.

Comment: It really depends on your individual setup, and how failover would be handled.  Given the same resource constraints, I wouldn't have hesitation for either.  HAProxy is just another process, and probably less memory intensive than RabbitMQ, so putting Redis there is fine from my point of view.  On the other hand, some people may want to separate the frontend-ish bits from the backend-ish bits, so that choice may rub those people the wrong way. It's up to you; there's no technical reason for one or the other (other than resource constraints).

Comment: Thanks for your advice @cjc. I think I will go with the HaProxy boxes to begin with, I can always change this quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The best location for installing Redis is /opt directory.

Because Redis that just needs one directory and will get all files/libraries relative to that directory can get one directory for itself in /opt/.

Comment: but on which set of boxes!

Comment: You can install in all boxes.Because it is available in source tree format, we have to download, extract and to compile it. So,better to keep it /opt dir.

Comment: I meant where would be best to install itfrom an infrastructure point of view. Would you normally cohost anything with haproxy?